# How to insert total number of lines in a new line before the first line command?

Tags: sed, word-count

I have thousands of .xyz files which are chemical coordinates like this one (for instance):

```
  Fe        0.000000000     0.000000000     0.000000000
   C        2.112450000     0.000000000     0.000000000
   C        0.039817193     1.817419422     0.000000000
```

I searched a lot for a simple command, like sed or head and tail, to write the counted number of lines on top of the file (with making a newline \n and with two spaces before the total number) but couldn't be successful.
I would really appreciate any help given.
The output mst be like this:

```
  3
Fe       0.000000000     0.000000000     0.000000000
C        2.112450000     0.000000000     0.000000000
C        0.039817193     1.817419422     0.000000000
```

Comment: @John Zwinck thanks for editting

Comment: something like `cat <(printf "  $(wc -l < file.xyz)\n") file.xyz` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as a composite command:

```
(wc -l < fileA && cat fileA) > outputA
```

Note that I used `<` there to make sure `wc` does not print the filename on the first line.  On Mac OS at least, it does if you don't use redirection like that.

---

Edit: If you need to apply the same to many files:

```
mkdir output
ls *.xyz | while read filename; do
    (wc -l < $filename && cat $filename) > output/$filename
done
```

---

Just for fun, here's a command that you should **not** use, but works in some cases:

```
tee xxx < fileA | wc -l > xxx # don't do this
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first command works perfect for one file, but in the situation that I have more than 5000 files, what changes do I have to apply to this command in order to preserve filenames and doing it for all the files respectively? ( "*.xyz" for instance)

Comment: @Amir: I added an example of writing a loop over all `*.xyz` files.

Comment: thank you very much, it solved my problem in a perfect way. I really appreciate your help

Comment: The loop breaks for filenames with spaces and would be better as `for filename in *.xyz; do`, IMO.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Your version fails if there are too many files.  OP specified "thousands of files" so I prefer using `ls`.  An industrial grade solution would use `find` instead.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of that. I ran a quick experiment to create a command line longer than `ARG_MAX` on my system (2097152), but actually it's `ls` that blows up, and not the shell `for` loop. According to [this](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/), the `for` loop is actually the cure for commands that fail with a too long argument (but it's slow). (It also points out that the fast solution would be `find`, as you mentioned.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed '1i \
'$(wc -l < file.xyz) file.xyz
```

To process multiple files with `find` and edit the files *in place* using the `-i` flag:

```
find . -name '*.xyz' -exec sh -c 'sed -i "1s/.*/$(wc -l < {})\n&/" {}' \;
```

**NB:** as the files will be edited in place with this command, you may want to first check the output. To do so, remove the `-i` flag after `sed`. If the command meets your needs, then add the `-i` flag again.